# Alpakka XML content between tags

Tags: scala, akka-stream, alpakka

Alpakka XML processing flow allows to read xml file element by element. But how to extract data between particular `StartElement` and `EndElement` including `StartElement` data? `subslice` is not an option because there is no constant prefix for needed elements.

Answer (score 1):

There is no operator like that out of the box, but you can write your own logic that filters out unnecessary elements that are emitted from `XmlParsing.parser`.

Drawing inspiration from [`subslice`](https://github.com/akka/alpakka/blob/master/xml/src/main/scala/akka/stream/alpakka/xml/Xml.scala#L436) implementation can be a good start.